# Swagger Spec - SmartDocs - Parameters name - alias

Tags: alias, swagger

Is there a way to set an alias to the name property of Parameters in swagger specs for SmartDocs to display different value?

For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: consumer_key
    in: formData
    description: >-
    Your Consumer Key (from My Apps)
    required: true
    type: string
```

When sending the request, it actually sends the consumer_key=ABC rather than client_id=ABC. The reason why I try to do this is, developer will get a consumer_key (as a client_id) after they register a developer app successfully.

Alternatively, I can map them in the description field 'This client_id is the consumer_key of your app.' or something like that, but I would like to see if there is a way to set 'alias' for the name field in swagger spec.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Swagger does not support alias names for parameters. And it would probably confuse the developers if the docs used different parameter names than in the actual request.

Use `description` to explain where the parameter value comes from. This will be enough.